# c++ parse from string using template

Tags: string

In C++, I want to get value from string.

I know there are functions like stoi, stol, stof...

But can I write a function that includes all of them? like using a template to infer the data type?

```
template<typename T>
T fromString(const std::string& s){
    // do something here
    // call stoi, stof according to typename T
}

string si = "1234";
int integer = fromString<int>(si);
string sf = "1234.1234";
float float_point = fromString<float>(sf);
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp He wants a value from the string, not a string from a value.

Comment: @mascoj Ok. Missed that....duh.

Answer (score 1):

*Cannot comment yet*, hence this ...

Not clear if you're looking for a single function, or templated (overloaded) functions? This would work: Have no default implementation with return type T, and specializations / usage so:

```
template<typename T> foo(const std::string& str) {}
template<> int foo(const std::string& str) {return atoi(str.c_str());}
template<> double foo(const std::string& str) {return atof(str.c_str());}
...
const std::string str1("1234"); const std::string str2("12.34");
const auto iVal = foo<int>(str1);
const auto dVal = foo<double>(str2);
```

Note the absence of specialization in the function name with the template function specialization, of course it appears as a return type.

Comment: The default implementation you wrote doesn't return anything! Otherwise I think this is what OP is looking for, template specialization. This might be one of the few cases where template specialization should be used instead of overloading.

Comment: Initially I had a pure template function declaration, no null body, and it worked as expected. Then I tried the null body, just to be sure, in MSVC, and was surprised that this also worked in MSVC.